# Как исключить из статистики неудачный запрос JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Доброе утро коллеги.
Есть алгоритм действий шлем запрос на бэк, если первый запрос не удачный, то через пять секунд шлем второй. Нужно не показывать первый не удачный запрос, если второй удачный.
Подскажите кто сталкивался как реализовать такое на JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно  "не показывать" только текущий результат пока второй запрос не начался, как только отработал последний [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) результат уйдет в [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)ы и в [.jtl файл](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode).

Если вдруг второй запрос не пройдет то двух ошибок в логах не будет, будет только последняя.

Если вас это устраивает - используйте примерно такой [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) код в [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor):

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

В противном случае можно убрать "ненужный" результат из .jtl файла используя [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), любой текстовый редактор или опять же Groovy код где-нибудь в [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group).